# cpan "Set::IntervalTree " or "Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization" doesn't work - I explain below the complete error log

Tags: perl, cpan

Here I explain more about troubles installing some Perl libraries:

1. trouble installing Set::IntervalTree
   ** I installed g++ - still the same issue
   ** I installed miniconda, and tried to conda the package - still having the same issue

here are the complete error logs:

** I copy part of it - as it is too long!

```
cpan Set::IntervalTree

Can't locate ExtUtils/CppGuess.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at Makefile.PL line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 11.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
  SLOYD/Set-IntervalTree-0.12.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

2. I face similar problem trying to cpan Algorithm::ExpectationMaximization

```
one dependency not OK (Math::GSL); additionally test harness failed
  C:\Strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AVIKAK/Algorithm-ExpectationMaximization-1.22.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Comment: Yeah, but you left out the relevant parts. As always, the *first* error message is usually the most relevant, not the last. In both cases, you appear to have missing dependencies.

Comment: Which version of perl are you using? Which Windows version?

Comment: *"one dependency not OK (Math::GSL)"* I think you need to use MSYS2 or Cygwin to install Math::GSL on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of the full log and post the link to it here. If you are philosophically opposed to GitHub, I believe there are other places you could post, but I don't know how permanent they are.
2. `cpan` and its related programs all (I believe) have options to automatically install dependencies which you do not already have installed. I wonder if deleting you cpan config file and reconfiguring to make sure that that option is set would help.
3. If the log of the run does not show it, make sure to add the output of `perl -V` to the gist. Perl version info helps in these situations.

Comment: `cpan` already installs dependencies. It's not an option at all. There's no sense in deleting the config to change that. I believe his issue is that he's missing the libgsl.